# Django ImportError: cannot import from models

Tags: python, django

I have a `utils.py` file in an app directory at the same level as `models.py`. I am trying to import a class (a model) in `utils.py`:

```
from models import TeamConstraint
```

My IDE does not report any conflict, however when running the server I am getting an `ImportError`:

```
ImportError: cannot import name TeamConstraint
```

I tried checking for circular dependencies, there is a file `tasks.py` also in the same level as the rest that imports from `utils.py`:

```
from scheduler.utils import current_indie_teams, matchcount_by_week
```

Although I don't understand why here `scheduler` needs to be included explicitly, while when trying to import a model it is not required (or so says PyCharm at least).

I am trying to figure out how to solve this.

Comment: `from .models import TeamConstraint`

Comment: The import is always relative to your `PYTHONPATH`(es). You will have to use a relative import as @e4c5 suggested or an absolute from the projects folder like: `from your_app.models import TeamConstraint`.

Comment: @e4c5 Oh right forgot about that. Still getting the `ImportError` though.

Comment: @KlausD. I get an `ImportError` using an absolute path as well.

Comment: is utils.py something you are trying to run from the command line?

Comment: @e4c5 No it is just a file with utility functions.

Comment: By the way importing locally in the function solves the problem, but I don't see why it should work this way and not the other.

Comment: django throws such error when it is trying to import from modules at the same level at the same time so we defer importing one of these so there is no clash.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `from models import TeamConstraint` it's not clear what `models` is.
It could be a different app with the name models or it could be the file in the same folder. It's better to be explicit than implicit.

Try using an absolute import `from scheduler.models import TeamConstraint` or if you really want to use a relative import do so as such `from .models import TeamConstraint` (Notice the . before models)

Also it seems like you are using Python3 but your PyCharm is configured for Python2, else it would warn you.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you get import errors, try delaying one of the imports.
here place 'from models import TeamConstraint' in class or function instead.